# How should I deal with editing small code errors in otherwise good answers?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've had the following problem a few times in the last week alone:

Someone has answered a question, and the answer is good, with the exception of a typo in the code. For instance, in an answer to a C++ post:

```c++
int main() {
    MyClass obj(); // This is wrong, declaring a function prototype.
}
```

All that is needed is to remove the parenthesis and the answer is completely correct.

The error may not have been pointed out in a comment, or it has been pointed out, but the answerer has not fixed it.

What is the recommended policy for such cases? Should I edit the post and add some random tautology at the end just to fill up the required characters for a minimal edit.

Should I simply leave the post alone with its errors?

Or, is there another established practice?

Comment: Is a `teutology` when a person of Germanic descent says something obvious?

Comment: @dg99 Most definitely. Or in this case, a Norwegian disregarding the spell checker.

Comment: If it's a small typo that makes the answer correct then it's ok to edit it (or suggest an edit). If it may change the meaning of the answer then you should leave a comment to the author pointing out the mistake. I would never say leave it unless you are unsure of how to handle it but a comment never(?) hurts anything.

Comment: @codeMagic Any thoughts on how I would deal with the "minimum character limit"? Or isn't that a problem once my rep rise high enough?

Comment: @StianV.Svedenborg When you get to 2k rep, you can make edits to anything without approval and they can be as minor as you'd like: until then, your edits have to be 6+ characters and they go into a review queue for others to decide whether they are beneficial to the post.

Comment: No, it's still a problem with higher rep. I use some filler words but try to think of something that makes it less of a filler (ex. simple explanation). If you only need a few characters then a few "..." will work but more than that and you should be able to think of something to add

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant for a comment. What @AstroCB said if you are talking about the suggested edit.

Comment: Sweet, I guess I can live with this for a few more weeks.

Comment: I've found that people are grateful if I perform such fixes. Just **make sure** the edit is correct.

Comment: Personally, I am always thankful if someone edit my answers if he can provide anything useful like correcting a mistake, adding more insightful ideas.

Comment: @Boann +1. Having recently edited code in an answer to fix what I thought was a typo and crucially *not bothering to test it* and subsequently looking like an incompetent fool, I can attest to the value of *making sure* your edit is actually an improvement and not your own misunderstanding. OP wasn't pleased to say the least.

Comment: There are _always_ 6 characters to edit; it's never a problem. If you have a problem finding 6 characters just ping me and I'll find 6 for you.

Comment: @Ben this simply isn't true. I know that Jeff Atwood himself made this claim, and therefore a lot of people accept is as true, but it actually isn't.

Comment: It's nothing to do with Jeff Atwood @jwg. I'm able to think for myself, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158708/179419. The last person to claim this to me deleted their question but I changed about 300 characters.

Comment: I'm glad that you can think for yourself but still unconvinced @Ben.

Comment: I think a troll has infiltrated MetaStack....

Comment: I just edited this question to include a comma. One measly character.

Comment: The edit right before that only manipulated an apostrophe.

Comment: Sometimes it is useful, sometimes it isn't

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Make sure that it is syntactically correct (*for the code version they are using*) to make the change that you (or others) have suggested
2. If the user hasn't made the change in a reasonable amount of time, make the change, be sure to explain in the explanation box on the edit page.
3. Leave a comment saying you have done this and ask for explanation if they disagree *and rollback the edit* so that you know why they have it in the code.

---

Sometimes when correcting logic some people may accidentally forget semi-colons or other syntax that is necessary for the code to function in real life, I personally wouldn't mind if someone corrected the syntax in an answer of mine.

Comment: Personally I like adding, that OP can roll back in revisions, even though there's no magic link for that ;)

Comment: Am I missing something or is this answer? This doesn't explain what to do about the 6 char limit, which I thought was part of OP's problem.

Comment: @jwg, then you can only let the OP on the answer know about it, otherwise find some other things in the answer to fix. At Least until you hit the 2k Rep mark,  which is easy if you answer questions for 10 days in a row and your answers are good enough to get 20 votes in total each day.

Answer (score 7):

Fix it.  [The help centre empowers you to correct minor mistakes.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)  Actual practice, among reviewers, moderators, and folks active on meta, is at odds with the help centre.

Comment: Hmmm, seems the help center has a minor contradiction. "Edits are expected to be substantial", and yet "Common reasons for edits include: ... To correct minor mistakes...". So seems everyone wins?

Comment: @user3580294: It has tons of contradictions and little bits that fly in the face of established practise.  Nobody really seems to mind.  Fixing mistakes is a good thing, though.

Comment: @user3580294: That's a question of interpretation. I would argue that fixing a minor **mistake** in the core of the answer (which includes code) can be a substantial edit. Minor **edits** are more typically fixing things that are purely cosmetic and don't make a significant difference to the reader of the post.

Comment: @RetoKoradi That's a good point that hadn't crossed my mind. I agree, fixing a minor mistake could indeed count as a substantial edit.

Answer (score 2):

I say fix it as long as its clearly an oversight by the author and it's obvious they meant something else in context.

Personally, I genuinely appreciate when others edit small coding mistakes I make in answers, whether they leave a comment or not. Actually, I find the comment unnecessary as well as it is clear when somebody edits my post, and their name appears in the edit history, and the edit description field can be used to give the reasons.

For example, I recently gave an answer in Java after having coded in C++ all day and accidentally used `->` instead of `.` everywhere. Somebody came in and [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24597281/revisions) those all for me. No comment or explanation was necessary. It was nice to know that somebody "had my back".

You just have to take care that your fix is *correct* and *does not change the intended meaning*. To *not* appreciate somebody correcting unintentional small errors in your post seems like a mistake to me.