# Should we correct incorrect answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

It's old, but I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21293421/4022608) today.  It is incorrect, and someone had submitted a minor edit that that fixed it and had been approved.

This edit was then rolled back, with the following comment left:

> I did a roll-back because, although the answer itself may be wrong, it
>   is still a genuine answer. If you (correctly) think the answer is
>   wrong, you have two options: 1) add a comment or 2) add a new answer
>   (or do both). Don't change someone's answer to such that it says
>   something completely different from what was intended by the author.

While I understand that we can downvote and/or flag answers (e.g. as [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251393/4022608) points out) if it is just a simple and minor error on the part of the answerer (in this case, one word), then shouldn't a correction be accepted?
Obviously re-writing an answer from scratch changes the entire nature of it. In that case you write your own answer and downvote / flag.

This may be a case that an absolute rule along the lines of `minor edits only` (e.g. grammar, spelling, typo corrections) is preferable, however I would say that the edit did not violate the following:
`"This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost"`

addendum: for code syntax corrections, it seems that this is accepted behaviour (see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265862/4022608)). Why would this not be the case here?

Edit: I should probably point out that the (currently incorrect answer) has upvotes, which could lead to someone (not reading the comment) thinking that it is correct.

Comment: I tend to find people get touchy if an edit is anything more than a simple typo fix. I leave a comment and point out any flaws. If the answer is just flat out wrong, I write my own answer.

Comment: Well, for starters, the edit was wrong, and the original answer was correct, so there really is not question whatsoever that this particular edit was wrong.  Of course, the answer is a low quality answer in that it doesn't explain the terminology it uses, why the differences are important, etc. but it is *correct*.

Answer (score 10):

I think the general consensus that I've seen around here is to (as you point out) not deviate from the author's intent or fundamentally change the answer to something else. So:

**No**, you should not edit incorrect answers to make them correct.

**Yes**, you should edit answers to resolve minor technical inaccuracies that are not bound to the intent of the answer and do not meaningfully change the answer.

The question you referenced was "What is the difference between `printf()` and `cout` in C++?". The answer given was "`printf()` is a function whereas `cout` is a variable." The claim that "`cout` is a variable" is a **key** part of that answer. It may be wrong (apparently it is **not** wrong, and it is a global variable, and I didn't know that!). But changing it in the way that you did totally changes the answer.

If the user had answered "`printf()` is a function and `boost::cout` is an object", then I would argue that editing to remove `boost::` or changing to `std::` would be a perfectly fine technical adjustment that clearly does not deviate from the intent of the post or meaningfully change the answer. The author clearly thought that `cout` was in the `boost` namespace and we're changing it, but the author's main point (`printf` being a function and `cout` being a object) is retained.

It gets a little fuzzy occasionally, but that seems to be what the community is for.