# What happens when all answers become delegitimized?

Tags: support, answers

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037772/swift-enum-multiple-cases-with-the-same-value/62884952) is a fairly well known and old question in Swift.

It asks this question:

> Can an enum have 2 cases where both raw values are the same?

Swift is very clear that is is not the case. So explains the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28049473/13426627), and practically all other answers.
However, I have discovered that every single answer to this question is incorrect. Because I discovered how to solve it: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62884952/13426627)

My answer is due to a bug (I will need to report it, and most likely it will be fixed).

However, there's a few things we need to keep in mind:

- It will not be fixed on all older versions of Swift. It will continue to exist as a solution forever.
- What happens if the Swift engineers decide, for future versions of Swift, "Hey let's not actually fix it" or "Let's implement this!"

What would happen to the 7 answers on this topic? Are all they delegitimized? Do they need to be edited?

---

**After reading my post, you can see that this is different than questions like:**

- [How to handle historical, highly upvoted but completely incorrect answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers) - All answers will technically be correct if Swift implements the bug fix. In such a short time frame, and such an odd bug, I feel like it would be petty to edit or flag these posts as suggested by this topic. This one does not pertain to accepted answers.
- [Should we correct incorrect answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272511/should-we-correct-incorrect-answers) - This also one does not pertain to accepted answers.
- [Old Q, New Tech, New Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258363/old-question-new-technology-new-answer),  [Introduce Obsolete Flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272651/introduce-an-obsolete-answer-vote) - None of the answers are obsolete. In fact, they will all be relevant if the bug is fixed.

Comment: They're not "delegitimized". You just found a better answer. Let the community vote on it. That's how the system works here.

Comment: *It will not be fixed on all older versions of Swift. It will continue to exist as a solution forever.* Hmm, I do see your point, but I also think that "forever" has changed a lot in recent years, especially for younger langages like Swift. In other words, your discovery based on a bug will probably run on less than 1% of devices 5 years from now. The status quo will most probably remain the same, as always.

Comment: As you say, it's a bug, so the other answers are still relevant for anyone who doesn't want to rely on unintended behavior.

Comment: Nothing has been made illegitimate: that code segfaults compilers previous to 5.2: https://godbolt.org/z/Kjb4zv

Comment: @jscs Thank you!! I just tried on Swift 5.0, it's the same thing. It must be related to this [SR-12998](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12998) I reported.

Comment: @jscs **>>>** I just figured out how to bypass the segfault on Swift 5.0. It had to do with the one Raw Value being explicitly `true`. If they are *all* Ints, it will work. Check out my updated answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62884952/13426627)