# Needs to be edited but can't due to edit limit

Tags: discussion

My question is about cases like this one:

[composite foreign key not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933623/composite-foreign-key-not-working/31934099#31934099)

The answer there is:

[image]

I wanted to edit the post so that the code part will be in code markdown, as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE cart ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (product_id , sub_product_id);
```

However it doesn't let me because

> Edit must be at least 6 characters

This edit is required for better readability of posts - it's hard to read code that isn't styled correctly. The limitation in this case prevents the improvement of the post.

Comment: This question already have an answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253675/1579771).

Comment: I've edited it. I could have just done what you ask _but_ I deliberately used a bit more to make the post that little bit more comprehensible. It's more than 6 characters. Far more than 6 characters...