# Why was this edit correcting a software version number rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

In this post [Error installing XercesC with MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526275/error-installing-xercesc-with-mingw) there is a version number from the future mentioned. I suggested correcting this number because I found it annoying (making me check the most current version of xerces-c), but [the edit suggestion was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9620663) with different reasons, the majority voting for

```
This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier
to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely
superfluous or actively harm readability.
```

Why should wrong version stand uncorrected?

Comment: Can't read the minds of revewers, but could be that you added a series of x's to get around the minimum character limit.

Comment: @psubsee2003: That'd do it for *me*, certainly. (Filler chars to make edits work should always be within HTML comments or otherwise invisible, and only if there's no other possible improvement to make instead.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without speaking to each of the individual reviewers, no one can actually tell you exactly why the reviewers rejected it, but one can theorize it's because you tried to circumvent the minimum character limit by adding a series of x's to the post.

While it does sometimes prevent someone from suggesting an edit to fix a small but critical typo, the minimum character limit exists for a reason, and that is to force editors to suggest substantial edits.  Why is this necessary?  It has been discussed to death, so I encourage you to read through some of this discussion including the posts in the "linked" section of each question (and if you are thorough, you will find a more acceptable workaround):

- [What to do with the 6 character edit limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240295/what-to-do-with-the-6-character-edit-limit?lq=1)
- [Can we fix the character limit for edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253675/can-we-fix-the-character-limit-for-edits)
- [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/change-this-behavior-to-allow-for-spelling-corrections-and-the-like-edits-must)

I did mention a work around above, but in this case I don't think it would have been necessary.  A quick glance and I saw a couple of items that you could have edited instead of trying to work around the edit requirements, for example, the last sentence is very clumsy to read.  You could have rewritten to make it easier to understand.

Another option rather than trying to work around the edit limit would have been to ask the OP in a comment to edit the post to fix the typo since he did acknowledge it was a typo.

And just a side note, on your edit comment.  While this probably would not have helped prevewnt rejection, you should have indicated in the edit comment that you were fixing a typo that was acknowledged by the OP in comments on the question.  The reviewers would not have seen that comment by the OP so would have had no idea the OP actually said the version was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

As has been said, no one can know exactly what was going on in the minds of the reviewers. However...

This was your edit comment:

> Corrected annoying version number from future; added some xxxxxx at the end to make the system accept my edit

This reads like you're just making up the version number. How do the reviewers know that you're using the version used by the OP?

What you were actually doing was correcting the version number to the one the OP was actually using, as confirmed by the OP in the comments. Write what you were actually doing:

> `Corrected version number as confirmed by OP in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526275/error-installing-xercesc-with-mingw#comment52926212_32526275`

This fits in the comment box...

You also added `xxxxxx` at the end in order to reach the 6 character limit. Quite a few people think that you should be easily able to correct a typo without having to change 6 characters. However, I'm yet to *ever* find a problem finding 6 characters to change that all improve the post.

I've [made the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32526275/revisions). I've removed 22 characters and added 36 characters, excluding whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this one.