# What to do if the answer needs a 1~5 chars' fix which is crucial?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, character-limit

While submitting an edit of an answer (not by me), it shows that it needs at least 6 (six) characters edited.

What if it needs a (1~5) characters(or whitespaces, e.g. for Python) edit which is crucial?

What is ideal to do here?

**For example,** 
take this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13003653

It is the correct answer, but whitespaces of 2-lines were off. Technically, to make it correct, it required just inserting 2x2=4 spaces, but I had to update other lines' whitespace to make the minimum for submission.

Comment: Related: [Why was this edit correcting a software version number rejected?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306794/why-was-this-edit-correcting-a-software-version-number-rejected)

Answer (score 5):

Leave a comment for the author of the post. In the example case, they were just seen 17 hours ago.

Comment: And most of the time, there is usually something else to fix.  An absolutely perfect post with only 1 error of <6 chars is uncommon

Comment: @psubsee2003 Agreed. It's pretty rare that I can't find more than 5 characters to improve upon. Except in my own posts, of course. ;)